# I am having trouble updating in ubuntu 12.10 64-bit?

Tags: 12.10, apt, updates, update-manager

when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: Have you tried upgrading from the upgrade manager?   [Upgrade Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade)

Comment: I just tried again using the update manager..it doesn’t give any errors, but doesn’t give any new updates..It might be possible that there isn’t any new updates..I find that hard to believe, though.

Comment: Do you have any other ppas?  See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220019/unable-to-update-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: Oh, it says "You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems" try running that.

Comment: I just have a couple canonical partners, http://ppa.launchpad.net/paul-clinbing/ppa/ubuntu precise main, http://ppa.launchpad.net/paul-clinbing/ppa/ubuntu precise source code

Comment: oh, I ran apt-get update..game me the same thing..maybe there hasn't been many updates in a few days..i got one this morning..but it's been wierd for like a week? idk

Answer (score 0):

You've made an upgrade from 12.04, Canonical Precise PPA was left behind.
In terminal type `ls /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists*`.
The result should be something like this:

> /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-amd64_Packages
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release.gpg

...plus they Quantal counterparts

> /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal_partner_binary-amd64_Packages
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal_partner_binary-i386_Packages
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal_Release
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal_Release.gpg

...if so, just delete the precise versions.