# Unable to update Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: update-manager

Once I tried to install Banshee on Ubuntu 12.10 and added that PPA. But somehow the installation failed due to internet failure. The problem is from then, when I try to update Ubuntu, update task fails and the error is due to that bandshee PPA. I don't know how to solve the problem.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

GUI-based repository management is normally accomplished via "Software Sources". This interface can be accessed via several methods. For the latest versions of Ubuntu, the easiest way is to go through the "Ubuntu Software Center". Open the software center, then from the Edit menu select "Software Sources". You will have to enter your password to change settings in this window.

[image: software-sources]

Select the "Other Software" tab and uncheck the offending repository.  This will disable the repository (You can re-enable it this way too).

[image: other software tab]

Source: [Ubuntu Repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Removing_.26_Disabling_Repositories)