# How do I Uninstall Deepin Software Center?

Tags: uninstall

I installed Deepin Software Center yesterday.But now when i want to uninstall it, i cant find it on Ubuntu Software center 'installed' section.
Do not know the SUDO CODE too. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you explain how you added it?  Did you add a ppa?

Comment: Actually I am new to Ubuntu Terms. What is PPA? I added Deepin Software Center by giving a code to the terminal, which i found in a website. Installation was easy and fast. Now i have even uninstalled it smoothly with the help of @Vitor. Now there is some REMOVE PPA thing goin on, which is a bit quirky for me. Can you explain how to do it?

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/220023/44179) for removing repo's and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) for what they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

> sudo apt-get remove deepin-software-center

You should also open software sources and remove the ppa that you added to install deepin software center.  There's no point getting updates from the ppa if you no longer have the software.

Comment: Fabri...How do i remove PPA..? Sorry..new to Ubuntu

Comment: sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:put-the-ppa-here

Comment: I went to Software Sources - Other Software.

Answer (score 0):

I felt this is is much better comand as it removes everything related to deepin :

`sudo apt-get remove deepin-*`