# Can I just try another desktop enviromment?

Tags: desktop-environments

I've been using Ubuntu for a few years now, always just "as-is". I'm starting to think it could be fun to try another desktop environment than the default, but I'm somewhat reluctant to try it out - last time I did that (many years ago), it introduced lasting, detrimental and irreversible changes to my installation. I don't think trying out another desktop it worth that, so my question is: Is this still the case, or has it become easier to switch between desktop environments?

Comment: For trying out, I would try a Live USB with the flavor you want to test, and get a feeling for it that way.

Comment: For that virtual machines are nice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Known incompatibilities/conflicts when installing multiple specific desktop environments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195269/known-incompatibilities-conflicts-when-installing-multiple-specific-desktop-envi)  *I'm a lover of multiple-desktop/WMs on my boxes; I wrote an answer on this question that maybe worth reading*

Comment: Another possibly useful answer I've written on the topic can be found at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278057/is-installing-another-desktop-environment-on-a-stock-ubuntu-20-04-install-consid/1278061#1278061  (I've written other answers too, but I've found two...)

Comment: @ArturMeinild Yes - and no. I remember reading that exact question last time, and concluding that I should just try it out...which turned out to be a bad idea. So I guess I'll just - you know - not do it. But thanks!

Comment: How the additional desktops are installed matters in my opinion too..    However you do know how you can re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system (esp. easy with *flavors*) and not lose any of your datafiles (anything in $HOME isn't touched), including having the *manually installed* packages you added to your system (*those added post-install from Ubuntu repositories*) auto-reinstall... ie. even if you suffer some mistakes, you can usually be re-installed & back operational within 15 minutes...