# How to get rid of double title bar in Unity on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, unity, 22.04, titlebar

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and installed Unity alongside Gnome because of certain features which Gnome does not handle as well at this moment.

However, all apps which come with my Ubuntu installation with Gnome (including Firefox, Nautilus file manager, Software updater, etc.) have a double title bar as such:

[image]

Other apps which came with Unity (such as Nemo) and those which were installed manually do not have this problem.

I found a similar solution for Gnome answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252897/double-title-bars-two-title-bars-appear-in-ubuntu-20-04), but couldn't find one for Unity. How can I fix this double title bar on Unity?

*Note: I need to keep Gnome installation alongside Unity, and can not re-install my OS to an option like [Ubuntu Unity](https://ubuntuunity.org/)*

Comment: ... and how to file a bug report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK client side decorations appear to be messing with how Unity manages the header bar.

Add this to your preferred environment file (`/etc/environment` for all users or `~/.profile` for just yourself:

```
export GTK_CSD=1
```

or to run a single program, for example, GEdit, without decorations:

```
GTK_CSD=1 gedit
```

Beware that this might mess with GNOME desktop if you still use it, though it doesn't appear to break anything.

Comment: Hi John,  I pass along a hearty welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  You answer addresses the OP and gives the options that they need.  You might want to edit and add a reference where you found the information,  I search and found a couple, but none of them were concise; many were rants.  You steered clear of that tendency and provided unbiased accurate information.  Thank you and again, welcome.