# is there anyway to install multiple desktop environments clean and without interfering each other?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, desktop-environments

So, before, I have installed another desktop environment which after installation it made a startup sound, and changed one of my fonts, and things like these which I could never make them like before.

Also as it says  in [Will I have problems installing multiple desktop environments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266224/will-i-have-problems-installing-multiple-desktop-environments)

> However, desktop environments will often "argue" with each other and overwrite settings.

Made me sure it's not a random thing that just happened for me.

now after a while, again, It passed my mind to have multiple desktop environments. Is there anyway to install them without them arguing and interfering with each other and without overwriting settings and etc.. ?

Comment: The best way to do this is to have a separate partition for each operating system that has its own DE. I also suggest not having a common partition for the home directory, because each DE will over write config files in the user's home directory. (If you want to have a common Documents, Downloads, Music, etc. directories, you can always create a link from each user's home directory to a another partition that has these directories. This will keep everything clean and separate while allowing you to easily work on your files from any DE.)

Comment: You can fully install multiple Linux OS on a SSD or HDD. Just like installing Windows and Ubuntu on the same drive, only it is much easier as they all use GRUB bootloader.

Comment: thanks guys, but at this moment, Installing multiple Linuxes  is not my best option

Comment: It depends on, in my opinion  if the desktop share the same "roots". I would avoid gnome/unity/mate/cinnamon install together (gtk based) Or lubuntu/plasma (qt* based)

Comment: @nobody what about logging in into each of the desktop envs by different users and not opening two gtk based or two qt based desktops with one user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I tested installing other desktop environments alongside gnome,(I installed kde and cinnamon) and logging into each with a different user, so the config files of the envs don't interfere.

as long as I see, There will be no issue if you always use one desktop environment for each user.