# Can I triple boot windows 7, ubuntu 13.04 and kubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, windows, kubuntu

I have ubuntu 13.04 and windows 7.  I heard that kubuntu is more like windows, so I wanted to try it.  Is it possible to triple boot them?  If it is can you tell me how to.  I have installed ubuntu on a partition.

Comment: In my opinion, LXDE is closer to Windows than KDE, but that's just my opinion...

Comment: Ok thanks.  I just thought I read a lot of other sites that said kubuntu is closer.  Do you know how to triple boot though.

Comment: I personally don't think you need to, you can install the KDE environment inside of Ubuntu 13.04 alongside it without actually messing with the hard drive partitions.  Saves you the headache of dealing with partitioning for a triple boot environment.

Comment: Do I download KDE from the software center?

Comment: If you want the complete Kubuntu software package as well, then you can install `kubuntu-desktop`, and that'll install all the software that comes with Kubuntu as well, if you just want the KDE environment, I'd have to go look up what the specific packages are for that.

Comment: Thanks!!  Could you tell me what to look up to get the KDE environment?

Comment: If I want to install Kubuntu desktop from the terminal, what command would I use?  I know I am asking you a lot but thanks!!!

Comment: Voting to reopen since he doesn't actually have 3 different OSes to triple boot; just wants two different ubuntu desktop flavors.

Comment: Thanks dude!  Was the question closed?

Comment: Check this question out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/228503/is-it-possible-to-use-multiple-desktop-environments-on-same-system Much easier than triple booting ;) (@psusi Wouldn't you consider this a duplicate of that?)

Comment: If you are not tripplebooting pleas edit the question to refllect that.

Comment: @Seth, yes, that would be a more appropriate dup... good find.

Comment: I went to that question and I already installed kubuntu desktop and my grub menu shows kubuntu but when I log in it goes straight to ubuntu.  How do I go to kubuntu too?  I will try using the other question.

Comment: I am making a new question to find out how to choose between kubuntu and ubuntu when I login.  Please help me with that question.

Comment: If I want to download other environments how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to dual boot between ubuntu and kubuntu.  You can simply install Ubuntu and if you also want to try kubuntu, you just install the kubuntu-desktop package and can select between the two desktops when you log in.

Comment: Do I download KDE from the software center?

Comment: @askubuntu7639, the command line is `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: dude what just happened I downloaded kubuntu desktop and I restarted my computer and it gave me the option to boot kubuntu or windows.  Then I selected kubuntu and booted it.  It booted fine but it opened into ubuntu.  Why did that happen?  And also how do I use the kubuntu packages that were downloaded.

Comment: Should I ask another question about this?

Comment: @askubuntu7639, log out, and when you log in there is an option to choose which desktop you want to use for this session.

Comment: I just logged out and logged back in and it went to ubuntu without aking me anything.

Comment: I am making a new question to find out how to choose between kubuntu and ubuntu when I login.  Please help me with that question.

Comment: @askubuntu7639, you have to click on the knob next to the password box.

Comment: It works thanks.  Do I close the question if it has been answered?

Comment: If I want to download other environments how do I do that?