# Is there analternate for unity in 14.04?

Tags: unity-dash

Is there a way to put unity at the bottom of the screen or is there an alternative to unity?

Comment: Alternatively Use Auto-Hide option at appearance-setting. Or **Install** `classicmenu-indicator` or `indicater-synapse` etc packages which is displayed as applet.

Comment: [No you can't move the launcher.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher) As for an "alternative" check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available

Comment: Visit [derivatives](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives) or [flavors](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors) & Different [**Desktop-Environment**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) or [Unity-Alternatives](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/728203-how-to-replace-the-unity-desktop-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you mean the menu bar at the top, or the launcher which is at the left.  There is [an article](http://blog.ubuntulinuxguide.com/2013/02/how-to-move-unity-launcher-ubuntu-1110.html) which discusses how to move the launcher to the bottom to make Unity a bit more OSX like, and might work on 14.04

Otherwise you might examine some of the alternate desktops available to the gnome desktop.  Open the software center and search for desktop

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are many alternative desktop environment's other than utility. For example [Ubuntu Gnome](http://ubuntugnome.org/) 
and there are many other version's of Ubuntu you can check them [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives). One can use two Desktop Environment's in same kernel. For more details go [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228503/is-it-possible-to-use-multiple-desktop-environments-on-same-system)