# Run KDE and Unity

Tags: unity, kubuntu, kde

Is there a way to run Unity alongside KDE? I have installed Kubuntu/KDE and I am wondering if I can install Unity so I can switch back and forth between the two.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to use multiple desktop environments on same system?](http://askubuntu.com/q/228503/301745)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use unity in Kubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Use this command to install unity. You can choose the unity or KDE environment in the login screen.