# Install KDE without Kubuntu on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kde

Similar to [this question](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2090402), I want to install KDE on Ubuntu 16.04 **without** installing the complete Kubuntu system. I've seen [Ubuntu's InstallingKDE wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE), but it was last updated in 2014, and the recommended command doesn't work anymore:

```
sudo apt install kde-plasma-desktop
```

I've tried a few other guesses, but none of them work:

```
sudo apt install kde
sudo apt install kde5
```

Comment: Have you opened your package manager and searched for a KDE metapackage?

Comment: I can only find the `kde-plasma-desktop` package in [`trusty 14.04LTS` and `precise 12.04LTS`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kde-plasma-desktop&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). 
But maybe one of the dependencies, [`plasma-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/plasma-desktop), has what you need? (Probably not)

Comment: @Carolus, thanks for posting that. I'm not sure if that's what I want, but I'm a little concerned about trying it since installing xubuntu completely took over my system and required a reinstall to fix.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 yeah then maybe wait until someone more knowledgeable comes by.

Answer (score 2):

as this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228503/is-it-possible-to-use-multiple-desktop-environments-on-same-system) says, it's: `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends kubuntu-desktop`. it still works, just tried it.